# How do you play a canvas in a video element?

Tags: html, html5-canvas, html5-video

I've looked at a sample for [Streaming from canvas to video element](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/capture/canvas-video/) so I can see that the principle works but i can't get it to play/display a static image in the video.

Here is my code so far with an image borrowed from stackoverflow. How can I change my code to display the canvas as a video?

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('viewport');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
const video = document.getElementById('videoPlayBack');

make_base();

function make_base() {
    base_image = new Image();
    base_image.onload = function () {
        context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0);
    }
    base_image.src = "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/ico-binoculars.svg?v=d4dbaac4eec9";
}

const stream = canvas.captureStream(25);
video.srcObject = stream;
```

```html
<canvas id="viewport"></canvas>
<video id="videoPlayBack" playsinline autoplay muted></video>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are drawing a cross-origin image, this will thus taint the canvas and mute the CanvasCaptureMediaStreamTrack, resulting in no data being passed.

Keep your canvas untainted if you wish to stream it:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('viewport');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
const video = document.getElementById('videoPlayBack');

make_base();

function make_base() {
  base_image = new Image();
  base_image.onload = function () {
    context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0, 400, 300);
  }
  base_image.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
  base_image.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png";
}

const stream = canvas.captureStream(25);
video.srcObject = stream;
```

```html
<canvas id="viewport" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
<video id="videoPlayBack" controls playsinline autoplay muted ></video>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't get to save from a canvas if you draw "not your images" on it, because of the canvas security model (the moment you draw any image to it that isn't same origin, and doesn't explicitly have a CORS header that okays your use, you no longer have access to the pixels - not through ImageData, not through toDataURL, etc. etc).

To prevent the canvas from flagging itself as "tainted", see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image for what your options might be.